# Liénard–Wiechert potential and Gravity

Tags: general-relativity, gravity

If one takes the [Liénard–Wiechert Potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%C3%A9nard%E2%80%93Wiechert_potential), swaps the charge with mass of the point and replaces $\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}$ with G, one gets a time retarded potential for gravity. Taking the gradient gives an expression for the the acceleration a particle feels at that point due to gravity.

Of course this doesn't give General Relativity, but it introduces several corrections over Newton's original expression. The first term below is the inverse-square law scaled down by the  usual factor of gamma minus a similar term proportional to the particle's velocity. The second term is proportional to particle acceleration.

Do the velocity or acceleration terms have any relationship to a stress energy tensor?  What are their physical interpretations?

I'm assuming the stress energy tensor in the particle's rest frame is rest energy times the Dirac delta function at $T^{00}$ with all other terms zero and Stress-Energy tensor in question is the Lorentz transform to the lab frame in which the particle is moving at constant velocity. So, $T^{0\mu}=cp^{\mu}$.

Below $\vec{n}_s$ is unit vector between field point and particle location at retarded time $t_r$. $\beta_s$ is the ratio of the particle's speed to that of light.

[image: Correction term]

Comment: *Is there a relationship between this correction term and the stress-energy tensor?* The stress-energy tensor of what? The stress-energy of a point particle is zero except at the location of the particle.

Comment: *correction term proportional to particle momentum* No. That term is proportional to the particle’s acceleration ($\dot\beta$).